# Wanting to add a trail to sprite pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a simple Snake game that leaves a trail behind it self.

I have tried checking out pygame.display.update and alphasurf, but all I want is a rect to leave a simple trail behind itself.

Almost like it is creating duplicates of it self as it moves.

I also can't just remove screen.fill because I want to add other moving parts aswell

Comment: A simple way to do this is to keep a list of the historical co-ordinates of the snake "body" parts.  When the snake "grows", add a new element to the list.  To draw the snake on the screen, loop over the list, drawing each element.  When the snake moves, update each of the body part co-ordinates.   If every body part is identical, this can also be optimised such that only the head and tail need to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53643165/), one way you could do this is to create a transparent surface  with the size of the screen onto which you blit the objects with trails. It needs to be a per-pixel alpha surface which you can create by passing the `pygame.SRCALPHA` special flag.
Blit the objects and reduce the alpha of all pixels on the alpha_surf each frame by filling it with a transparent white and also pass the `pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT` flag so that only the alpha channel is affected.

An example would be:

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, pos, *groups):
super().__init__(*groups)
self.image = pg.Surface((50, 50), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('dodgerblue'), (25, 25), 25)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)
self.pos = Vector2(pos)
def update(self):
self.pos += self.vel
self.rect.center = self.pos
def main():
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
# Blit objects with trails onto this surface instead of the screen.
alpha_surf = pg.Surface(screen.get_size(), pg.SRCALPHA)
clock = pg.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
player = Player((150, 150), all_sprites)
while True:
for event in pg.event.get():
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
return
elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
if event.key == pg.K_d:
player.vel.x = 5
elif event.key == pg.K_a:
player.vel.x = -5
elif event.key == pg.K_w:
player.vel.y = -5
elif event.key == pg.K_s:
player.vel.y = 5
elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
if event.key == pg.K_d and player.vel.x > 0:
player.vel.x = 0
elif event.key == pg.K_a and player.vel.x < 0:
player.vel.x = 0
elif event.key == pg.K_w:
player.vel.y = 0
elif event.key == pg.K_s:
player.vel.y = 0
# Reduce the alpha of all pixels on this surface each frame.
# Control the fade speed with the alpha value.
alpha_surf.fill((255, 255, 255, 220), special_flags=pg.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
all_sprites.update()
screen.fill((20, 50, 80)) # Clear the screen.
all_sprites.draw(alpha_surf) # Draw the objects onto the alpha_surf.
screen.blit(alpha_surf, (0, 0)) # Blit the alpha_surf onto the screen.
pg.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
pg.quit()
```

Comment: I don't understand this at all